# .htaccess turn SSL off for specific directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I would like to turn SSL off for the /builder directory of my site.
I have tried many different .htaccess configurations, but either I am putting them in the wrong order or they do not work.

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /index.html /index.php
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cdghost.xyz/$1 [R,L]
ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html 
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
ErrorDocument 504 /504.html
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this. Why do you want to *actively disable security*?

Comment: I have a script running that does not work with ssl enabled.

Comment: I did not write the script, although I am working with the creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /index.html /index.php

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^((?!builder/).*)$ https://www.cdghost.xyz/$1 [R,L]
ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html 
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
ErrorDocument 504 /504.html
```

You can also use a RewriteCond to exclude /builder from the HTTPS rediretion :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/builder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cdghost.xyz/$1 [R,L]
```

The RewriteCond checks to ensure that the Requested uri is not **/builder/..** , if it's not /builder.., then the request is redirected to SSL.